# Inplace restoration of upper/lower part of distributed lower/upper triangular matrix

Tags: matrix, copy, transpose, triangular, scalapack

I wonder if there exists any Scalapack routine that may convert a triangular matrix back to a general one, i.e. copies the lower/upper part to the upper/lower part - I couldn't find it yet.
I know there exists an easy workaraound using p?geadd with manipulation of the diagonal, but that one consumes twice as much memory as theoretically needed and I can't afford that...
So it seems strange to me, that Scalapack/PBLAS doesn't provide any routine solving this relative simple problem. If anybody knows more than I please let me know!

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a dangerous solution:

1. delete missing triangle of C
2. perform pdgeadd('T',C,C)
3. divide all elements of given triangle of C by two

It works, but I don't know if there are any limitations, since it's theoretically forbidden calling pdgeadd with a A and C referring to the same memory...